# Can't use Java 7 from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed openjdk-6-jre from the package manager, then I installed Eclipse, and this was the default JRE.

Now I needed to install, in addition to 6, also Java 7, so I installed openjdk-7-jre from the package manager. However, in Eclipse I still see only JRE 6. Also from the command line I see only java 6:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

How can I use JRE 7 from Eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make your new Java 7 installation the default one run this on shell -

```
> sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

To simply use Java 7 in your project without making it the system default go to `Configure Built Path` > `Libraries` > `Add Library` > `JRE System Library` > `Installed JREs` > `Add` > `Standard VM` > `Directory` and select the location where you installed the JVM.

Also change the `Properties` > `Java Compiler` > `Compliance Level` to 1.7

Edit:

To know the location of your JVM run -

```
> sudo find / -name rt.jar
```

The output on my system is -

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/rt.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

This tells me that `jdk` is in `/usr/lib/jvm/`

Comment: "select the location where you installed the JVM"

I installed the JVM using the package manager. How do I know where the package manager has put it?