# Can't switch compliance level in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

**So after reading another question post I realized my question had changed. It is essentially, why can't I change my compliance level in Eclipse from 1.6 to 1.7 but I'm going to leave the body of my question as it was typed originally.**

This is a very specific question but I'm going through a series of Java courses online and one of the lessons deals with switch. The example code uses switch with strings (both the course and I use Eclipse). When I try to run the code it gives me an error stating
"Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted"

I understand this is because strings can only be used with switch in Java 7. Thus I went about installing Java 7 in terminal using some instructions I found online. Afterwards Eclipse wouldn't run at all. I went to switch back to Java 6 and found I was running Java 7 Oracle but had option to change to Java 7 OpenJDK so I did. Eclipse is working again but I still get the same error as before. Why is this? And is there a way to fix it?

For some added info, here's what terminal returns when I type in  "sudo update-alternatives --config java" to switch between versions.

```
glitch@glitch-Inspiron-1720:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for glitch: 
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1062      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1062      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:"
```

As you can see I'm currently using java-7-openjdk where as before I was using java-7-oracle (which resulted in Eclipse plain out not working) and before that I assume I was using java-6-openjdk (this is what I run Minecraft in after all but who knows).

More specifically I'm using:

```
glitch@glitch-Inspiron-1720:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

I looked at this question: [Can't use Java 7 from Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226044/cant-use-java-7-from-eclipse)

I tried following the instructions given therein all the way up to changing Properties > Java Compiler > Compliance Level to 1.7

I found the location of my JVM was /usr/lib/jvm/ but when I put this in for JRE home in Eclipse it gives me this error: "Target is not a JDK Root. Java executable was not found"

I am quite frustrated. Can anyone help? Also, please forgive my ignorance, I am very new at all this.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! I uninstalled and reinstalled Java and changed the location of my JVM to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386`. The solution was much simpler than I thought. Now I feel very silly.